# How can I add a badge to this Bootstrap website?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to learn front-end. I'm starting with a project in Bootstrap, but I'm stuck on this issue. I want to add badges like in this design I made. Although if I try to add it, the alignment is incorrect and the site is messed up. Can somebody give it a shot?

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row p-4 gap-4 py-md-5 align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div class="list-group">
        <label class="list-group-item d-flex gap-3">
            <span class="pt-1 form-checked-content">
                <strong>Title</strong>
                <small class="d-block text-body-secondary">
                    <svg class="bi me-1" height="1em" width="1em"><use xlink:href="#calendar-event"></use></svg>
                    23 July
                    <svg class="bi me-1" height="1em" style="margin-left: 10px;" width="1em"><use
                            xlink:href="#alarm"></use></svg>
                    17:00
                </small>
                <small class="d-block text-body-secondary">
                    <svg class="bi me-1" height="1em" width="1em"><use xlink:href="#geo-alt"></use></svg>
                    1,5 km
                    <svg class="bi me-1" height="1em" style="margin-left: 10px;" width="1em"><use
                            xlink:href="#car"></use></svg>
                    19 min
                </small>
            </span>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary position-absolute top-50 translate-middle text-body-secondary"
                    style="right: 0; background: none; border-color: #00000059;" type="button">
                <svg class="bi m-1" height="1em" width="1em">
                    <use xlink:href="#edit"></use>
                </svg>
            </button>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: My design]

### What I've already tried:

I tried to add buttons and style them, but the result wasn't what I was expecting. It was added into the label so all of the text was shifted to the right like it was a horizontal grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the class `flex-wrap` to the label so that new flex items can wrap and then added a new div with the  `flex-basis` for `100%` so that it takes the whole row and then added the badges inside of it. And also for the alignment of the top contents I added some margin to the `span`.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row p-4 gap-4 py-md-5 align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div class="list-group">
        <label class="list-group-item d-flex flex-wrap gap-3">
            <span class="pt-1 form-checked-content mt-3">
                <strong>Title</strong>
                <small class="d-block text-body-secondary">
                    <svg class="bi me-1" height="1em" width="1em"><use xlink:href="#calendar-event"></use></svg>
                    23 July
                    <svg class="bi me-1" height="1em" style="margin-left: 10px;" width="1em"><use
                            xlink:href="#alarm"></use></svg>
                    17:00
                </small>
                <small class="d-block text-body-secondary">
                    <svg class="bi me-1" height="1em" width="1em"><use xlink:href="#geo-alt"></use></svg>
                    1,5 km
                    <svg class="bi me-1" height="1em" style="margin-left: 10px;" width="1em"><use
                            xlink:href="#car"></use></svg>
                    19 min
                </small>
            </span>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary position-absolute top-50 translate-middle text-body-secondary"
                    style="right: 0; background: none; border-color: #00000059;" type="button">
                <svg class="bi m-1" height="1em" width="1em">
                    <use xlink:href="#edit"></use>
                </svg>
            </button>

            <div style="flex-basis: 100%;">
                <div class="d-inline-block rounded-circle bg-danger text-center" style="width: 25px; height: 25px;">S</div>
                <div class="d-inline-block rounded-circle bg-success text-center" style="width: 25px; height: 25px;">A</div>
                <div class="d-inline-block rounded-circle bg-primary text-center" style="width: 25px; height: 25px;">E</div>
            </div>            
            
        </label>

    </div>
</div>
```